# PayPal JavaScript SDK with only client-id (no secret key)

Tags: paypal

is it possible in production mode to use the PayPal Javascript SDK only with the client ID without secret key? There are problems or is this possible? So only the client code without the server code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes; a [client-side only integration](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client) of the PayPal JavaScript SDK uses only a client-id.

A secret would instead be used to integrate server-side API calls (see the optional bullet #5 in [add and modify the code](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/#link-addandmodifythecode) here). That is something you should do if you need to record successful transactions in a database or anything of that nature.

Comment: I'll use PayPal IPN to collect all the transaction info and store data to database. I set IPN url to a PHP file that collect and save all. In the PHP file there isn't the secret key too.

Comment: The old asynchronous IPN service, really? Why would you want to use that for anything? The server-side API integration gives an immediate response, with none of the things that can go wrong that IPN has. Use it instead.